# MySQL not working after command 'use database'

Tags: mysql, sql

Please find my mysql prompt below

```
mysql> use my_nextone;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
```

The problem is it keeps on this state and does nothing at all . I tried restarting mysql but didn't help the cause . Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ain't doing nothing stuff, its working on fetching the database information . You have to be patient to allow it to fetch all info. Alternatively you can break it out using `ctrl + c` .

Now the best solution is to login to your mysql console using the -A option which will not load all the info but only the essential info which is required and the loading is quicker.

```
mysql -u root -P -A
```

Hope this helps .

Comment: Thanks :) Worked Perfectly